# calculate form fields using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, calculated-field

i want a jquery source to calculate my form

```
<form>
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="1000"> $1000
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="2000"> $2000
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="3000"> $3000
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="4000"> $4000
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="5000"> $5000

    <select name="number">
      <option name="number" value="1">1</option>
      <option name="number" value="1">2</option>
      <option name="number" value="1">3</option>
      <option name="number" value="1">4</option>
      <option name="number" value="1">5</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

must type*number and show total in text input

Comment: Have you tried anything -- please show code that does not work.

Comment: yes code pls. Note your values are all `"1"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind a [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) to both the `:radio` and `<select/>` elements to calculate the total.

```
$("select[name='number'], :radio[name='type']").change(function(){
    var $r = $(":radio[name='type']:checked");
    var $d = $("select[name='number']");
    if($r.length ==1){
        var t = parseInt($r.val(), 10);
        var n = parseInt($d.val(), 10);
        $("#result").val(t*n);
    }
});
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/zK5dR/)**

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I got

http://jsfiddle.net/04gqaLog/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='radio']").on("click", function() {
        var price = +$(this).attr("value");
        var quantity = +$("option:selected").text();
        $("#total").text(price * quantity);
    });
});
```

Fun Tip: You can use `+` to automatically convert a string to a number. It's much shorter than `parseInt` or `Number`.

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/enKV6/

```
$('select[name=number]').change(compute);
$('input[name=type]').change(compute);

function compute() {
    if ( $('input[name=type]:checked').val() != undefined ) {
        var a = $('input[name=type]:checked').val();
        var b = $('select[name=number]').val();
        var total = a * b;
        $('#total').val(total);
    }
}
```